# Why Does Android Studio Fail To Resolve 'View'?

Tags: android

It's not really a big deal but I was just curious as to why I have to manually add:

```
import android.view.View;
```

When most other imports I can automatically resolve with alt-enter?

Comment: That is weird. I can alt enter or it just pops up and ask me if I want to when I need it. I never have to type it out.

Comment: Yeah, I found it strange too. I'm not sure what's up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In File > Settings, open Editor > General > Auto Import and check if View is on the excluded list.

Comment: That was it. Any idea why it would be on that list without me specifically placing it there?

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to do by accident if you click the wrong thing while auto-completing. When there's multiple options for an import, it shows a menu of options with sub-menus. Clicking an option directly imports that class but opening a sub-menu has an option to exclude that import from auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Studio IDE choose `File | Invalidate Caches/Restart` and see if issue still exists

Comment: Still a no go. I was sure that would fix it, too. Odd.